# Need Help writing an XML Start Element in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xmlwriter

I've tried looking this up on MSDN, W3Schools, and a number of other sites, and nobody seems to have the answer. Here's my problem:

I'm trying to generate a start element for an XML document. The specific element that I need to create is this:

```
<ns1:getRecordsResponse xmlns:ns1="http://someurl/schemas">
```

Based on the research I've done, I've been able to get the second half of that element properly generated using this code:

```
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "ns1", null, "http://someurl/schemas");
```

I can't get the first part to generate properly, though. I've tried using writer.StartElement("ns1", "getRecordsResponse"), that same line but the names reversed, I've tried adding null as a third argument in each of the three spots, and it never comes out right. I've also tried to use the WriteElementString method, but I must not be doing that correctly because it throws invalid operation exceptions:

```
writer.WriteElementString("ns1", "getCitationsResponse", "http://someurl/schemas", null);
```

How can I get the element written properly?

Comment: Do you really need to use `XmlWriter` to start with? If you can get away with building your document in LINQ to XML, your life will probably be considerably simpler...

Comment: Something new to research, I guess. What I'm doing is taking information from a web service response and putting it directly into XML. If LINQ to XML can do that more easily than this, then great. If you have any great resources to help me figure that out, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Yes, LINQ to XML will *absolutely* let you to that. Search for LINQ to XML on MSDN and I'm sure you'll find a good starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to do what you want:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

class Test
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(Console.Out))
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("ns1", "foo", "http://someurl/schemas");
            writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "ns1", null, "http://someurl/schemas");
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
    }
}
```

Output (leaving out the XML declaration):

```
<ns1:foo xmlns:ns1="http://someurl/schemas" />
```

Looking at the [documentation for that overload of `WriteStartElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6baz118x.aspx) it should be clear why that works, as these are the parameters in order:

> - prefix
>     Type: System.String
>     The namespace prefix of the element.
> - localName
>     Type: System.String
>     The local name of the element.
> - ns
>     Type: System.String
>     The namespace URI to associate with the element.

Comment: Thank you. I had gotten confused by the possibility of putting the namespace URI in there, thinking that having it there and in the WriteAttributeString method call would have caused errors. I guess the XML is a little smarter than I am.